# Reordering subviews programatically won't work in a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, layoutsubviews, uitableview

I'm trying to reorder an image and a stackview (here called labelsStack) that are both contained in another stackview (here called stack). My goald would be to programatically reverse the index order of both subviews in order to change their postition at runtime (they are horizontally distributed, so theorically, if I reorder their indexes, it should reorder them in autolayout)

I have tried to update indexes, exchange subviews, sendViewForward etc from the Apple doc, but it doesn t work, here s the code of my tableViewCell :

```
     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


           }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = cellImage.bounds.height / 3
        cellImage.clipsToBounds = true

        if incoming {
        } else {
// as one of the many methods that didn't work
            self.stack.insertSubview(cellImage, belowSubview: labelsStack)
        }


    }
```

Comment: have you thought about setting up 2 sets of auto layout constraints and then switching them on and off, instead of using a stack?

Comment: sets of layout constraints ??? you mean programatically not in storyboard ?

Comment: I mean in storyboard, both sets, deactivate one set from storyboard and leave only the other active. Then create outlets for all of them and in code activate/deactivate what you need using the outlets.

Comment: I didn't know we could set Sets of constraints, and desactivate them in Storyboard, do you have any link that would talk about that, I don t seen to find anything online

Comment: Hmm Ill write it down with a couple of screenshot in the answer hold tight ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two alternative sets of constraints, one for the default order and the other for the inverse order. The default constraints are the one ending in 1

[image]

To initially deactivate the alternative setting you can use the inspector and change the *installed* checkbox

[image]

Your view controller should now have 6 outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topViewTopConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomViewTopConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomViewBottomConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var topViewTopConstraint2: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomViewTopConstraint2: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var topViewBottomConstraint2: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

now to activate the other set of constraints you can use:

```
    self.topViewBottomConstraint2.active = true
    self.topViewTopConstraint2.active = true
    self.bottomViewTopConstraint2.active = true
    self.topViewTopConstraint1.active = false
    self.bottomViewBottomConstraint1.active = false
    self.bottomViewTopConstraint1.active = false
```

and viceversa

Comment: that works perfectly, it s tricky but it does the job for what I need, Thanks for that :)